# loop in sql stored procedure and removing cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to modify a STORED procedure that is written by someone else.Basically the stored prcoedure uses a cusrsor to fetch the data from the table and then insert that data in another table. While fetching the code form another table, it also gets some distinct columns from another table Below is my code:

```
 Declare data_cursor cursor for

    Select emp_no, emp_name, event_date, Test_no, Code, Test_result
      From test_table1
     ORDER by emp_no

declare
   @empNo   varchar(100),
   @emp_name varchar(2000),
   @eventDate  varchar(20),
   @TestNo     varchar(100),
   @Code       varchar(100),
   @TestReuslt  varchar(100),
   @ProcessName  varchar(100),
   @FileProcess   varchar(200),
   @TestProcess   varchar(100),
   @countA         int,
   @error_count int

SELECT @ProcessName = (select distinct userID from test_table1)
SELECT @FileProcess = 'EW' + @ProcessName 
Select @TestProcess  = (Select distinct userID from test_Table1) + 'TXT'
select @countA = 0

  BEGIN tran
     OPEN data_cursor  
     fetch data_cursor into
      @empNo  ,
      @emp_name ,
      @eventDate  ,
      @TestNo  ,  
      @Code      , 
      @TestReuslt
  while (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
     begin
      insert into TESTTable2
            (
               empNum, empName, eventDate,TestNum, Code, TestResult, Testprocess,  ProcessName)
       values (@empNo, @emp_name, @eventDate , @TestNo , @Code, @TestReuslt, @TestProcess, @ProcessName)
   if @ ERROR > 0
            begin
                select @error_count = @error_count + 1
            end

        else
            set @record_id = @@Identity

        if @code like 'D%'
                  Insert into TESTTable3
            (testProcess, FileProcess, empNum)
                 values (@TestProcess,  @FileProcess, @empNo )
    if @@error > 0
            begin
                select @error_count = @error_count + 1
            end 

         set @countA = @countA + 1
       fetch data_cursor into
         fetch data_cursor into
      @empNo  ,
      @emp_name ,
      @eventDate  ,
      @TestNo  ,  
      @Code      , 
      @TestReuslt
if @ ERROR > 0
    BEGIN
        select @error_count = @error_count + 1
        end
    end 

     if @error_count > 0 
    begin
    rollback tran
    end
else

    begin /* @@error = 0 */
    commit tran

close data_cursor
deallocate data_cursor


     Insert into LOG_File
      (Name, Count, Processname)
       values ('Test1', @CountA,@ProcessName)

Select 'TotalCount' = @CountA
```

The reason, I have to modify the above STORED proc now is because of some APPLICATION changes, I am getting around 50 distinct userID's from test_table1 so the above subquery(SELECT @ProcessName = (select distinct userID from test_table1) doesn't work. How can I loop through the above stored proc so that each @ProcessName can get inserted in table TESTTable2 so in other words

I want to pass each userId one at a time and insert it in table test_table1 and other subsequent tables. I can declare another cursor to accomplish this, but I was wondering if there is any better way to rewrite this stored proc and not use the cursor at all.

because of my application changes all these three statements above are throwing the error:

```
SELECT @ProcessName = (select distinct userID from test_table1)
SELECT @FileProcess = 'EW' + @ProcessName 
Select @TestProcess  = (Select distinct userID from testTable1) + 'TXT'
```

I am using sql server 2005.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Really have no idea what should be done for the log_file table since that is not inside the cursor, but I think the rest would produce the correct results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @countA int=0

begin tran
begin try
    insert into TESTTable2(empNum, empName, eventDate,TestNum, Code, TestResult, Testprocess,  ProcessName)
        Select emp_no, emp_name, event_date, Test_no, Code, Test_result,userID+ 'TXT',userID
        From test_table1
        ORDER by emp_no

    SET @CountA=@@ROWCOUNT

    Insert into TESTTable3(testProcess, FileProcess, empNum)
        Select userID+ 'TXT','EW' + userID,emp_no
        From test_table1
        Where code like 'D%'
        ORDER by emp_no

    commit tran

    Insert into LOG_File(Name, Count, Processname) values ('Test1', @CountA,'@ProcessName')
end try
begin catch
    rollback tran

    SET @CountA =0
    Insert into LOG_File(Name, Count, Processname) values ('Test1', @CountA,'@ProcessName')

    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
end catch

Select @CountA [TotalCount]
```

Comment: The only problem with above code is if the inset to testTable2 fails, I don't get the ERROR message back. With the above stored proc with cursor, the insert to TestTable2 fails then I get the error message telling me the reason why the insert failed. Right now, I just get the message saying (0 row(s) affected). Is there any way, I can get the error message when I tried to execute the code.